Implementing Parallel RGB interface in STM32 with no LTDC
For my project, I need to use a parallel RGB interface (8 bits) to control a display using Nucleo-F411RE. The PCLK for the RGB interface is required to be a minimum of 1MHz.
However, the STM32-F411RE does not have any LTDC peripherals. So I implemented the parallel RGB interface using a timer interrupt at a 1MHz frequency and GPIO pins for sending data, but it does not work. For lower timer interrupt frequencies like 10 KHz, it can send data but for 1 MHz nothing of this code works, including UART transmit-receive and others.
So, is it possible to implement a parallel RGB interface in SMT32-F411RE (Or similar where there is no LDTC peripheral)? If possible then how?
Or, do I need to use another STM32 that has LTDC peripherals on it?

You're asking a 100MHz processor to handle interrupts at a 1MHz rate.  It's not going to be able to get any work done.  Can you put a simple FIFO on the board to act as a buffer?

@TimRoberts Can you elaborate about putting a simple FIFO as a buffer?

I don't know what your hardware design is, but you could put a simple 8-bit FIFO chip in between your GPIO lines and your display.  Then, you can shove a BUNCH of data out to the FIFO and have it stream into the display one at a time, while your CPU calculates the next bunch of pixels.

@TimRoberts I can try to implement but currently, my target is to use only one MCU to connect it to the display, and keep the hardware as simple as possible.

That's a very reasonable answer, but I think you're going to find it extremely difficult to drive a continuous 1MHz 8-bit parallel feed from the STM32-F411RE.

Should be doable with the DMA controller, no?
